# Add lines to connect faces

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

Is it possible to create lines/curves and "connect" all the faces, on every axis, like show in the image?

Comment: What defines which faces should be connected?

Comment: Distance. All faces has the same distance from each other. I'm trying raycast but no luck. For me this node is totally unpredictable.

Comment: How did you raycast, along that line? That can't work bc. your planes have a 0 z dimension. If you placed those cubes yourself, shouldn't the order be able to tell you which face is closest?

Comment: @ThiagoM. By distance you mean that each plane should be connected by a line to its closest neighbor planes in straight X, Y, and Z direction but not diagonal? This would result in a grid for the top left view? (Blender 3.1 has a *Dual Mesh* node. With the node you could convert the planes to a point. Not sure if this helps here)

Comment: "By distance you mean that each plane should be connected by a line to its closest neighbor planes in straight X, Y, and Z direction but not diagonal?"

Yes, exactly..i can add a point on every face, but how can i connect this points?

Comment: Are all the faces one object? And yes, how did you use the Ray Cast? I think this would easier to do with a script.